# Is there a difference between Adventure play after pass 2 In Plants vs. Zombies?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

In Plants vs. Zombies, after you pass all levels of Adventure Mode the first time, and start playing them a second time, there are 2 big differences:

1. The game (crazy dave?) pre-selects 3 plants for you in advance for each level, that you can't change.
2. There's a Yeti Zombie on a later level (4-10) which nets you a new Achievement when killed.

**Are there any differences between the "second pass" playing Adventure mode, and a "third pass" (e.g. playing the levels a 3rd time after you pass them second time around), or any sub-sequent passes?**

If it matters, it's a PC version.

Comment: It changes the count when you mouse over your golden sunflower